# Delete duplicate rows based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that has ID and EventDate. It has duplicate rows as I used Union of two tables. Now I got to have the rows with the minimum Eventdate and remove the other duplicates.

the table for eg

ID  | Date
--- | ---
1     | 10/27/1993
1      | 10/27/1994
2      | 10/17/1993
2      | 08/15/1993

Delete duplicate rows based on condition

Comment: pls, add some example

Comment: By the way what kind of database engine you use (MySQL, Firebird, etc)?

Comment: By the way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows?rq=1

Comment: I use sqlserver @venoel

Comment: I think just using the groupby function worked

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EventDate)
   FROM dbo.YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Comment: CTE lacks `from`

Comment: @JohnHC what are you talking about? ;). Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Use this!

```
    delete A
    (
       SELECT *,
              RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [COLUMN] ORDER BY EventDate ASC),*
       FROM dbo.Your_Table
    ) AS A
where rn > 1
```

Comment: How does the row number help?

Comment: this deletes the whole table

Comment: I do not want to delete based on Row number @FabianoCarvalho

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) (if we about MySQL) you cannot "delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery".

So

```
CREATE table1 LIKE table2;
INSERT table2 SELECT * FROM table1; 
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 WHERE table1.EventDate>t2.EventDate
);
DROP TABLE table2;
```

Where table1 you original table.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about Firebird it is enough

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1_1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT t1_2.id FROM table1 t1_2 WHERE t1_1.EventDate>t1_2.EventDate
);
```